# Postgres inherit indexes for partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, index, copy

I have a table with approximately 60 million rows that I have partitioned by state into 53 sub-tables.  These tables "inherit" the big table like so:

`CREATE TABLE b2b_ak (LIKE b2b including indexes, CHECK ( state = 'AK') ) INHERITS (b2b8) TABLESPACE B2B;`

My question is this:  if I do not build the indexes on b2b8 until after the copy statement completes, do the sub-tables inherit the indexes?  In other words I want to do this:

```
Create b2b8
Create b2b8_ak inherits b2b8
COPY b2b8 FROM bigcsvfile.csv
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY
```

And have the whole thing turn out to have created all of the indexes on the sub-tables.

Answer (score 12):

As explained before, `INHERITS` does not copy index definitions.

Therefore, you need to state both inheritance and index copying.

```
    CREATE TABLE sub_tab (LIKE tab INCLUDING ALL) INHERITS (tab);
```

Thank you, @dezso, for your remark.

Answer (score 2):

Even though [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html), states that all fields are synchronized between the parent table and its child (copied before).

> The optional INHERITS clause specifies a list of tables from which the
>   new table automatically inherits all columns.
>
> Use of INHERITS creates a persistent relationship between the new
>   child table and its parent table(s). Schema modifications to the
>   parent(s) normally propagate to children as well, and by default the
>   data of the child table is included in scans of the parent(s).

**It *does not* includes indexes**.

You can see from the examples in the documentation (or run a few tests on your own) to see that you'll need to build these indexes on a child table basis.

Comment: Yes I ended up trying out some builds to test and "inherits" does not result in the child tables being indexed after the are created if the parent child did not already have them in place from the start.  Unfortunately this ends up slowing down large csv imports via copy.

Answer (score 2):

INHERITS itself will never inherit indexes. it will inherit columns only.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)  "LIKE....Unlike INHERITS, the new table and original table are completely decoupled after creation is complete. Changes to the original table will not be applied to the new table"

Answer (score 0):

I made this function to build indexes on children tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION index_children (col_name text, parent_name text, index_type text) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpython3u AS
$_function$
    children = plpy.execute("SELECT c.relname AS child FROM pg_inherits JOIN pg_class AS c ON (inhrelid=c.oid) JOIN pg_class as p ON (inhparent=p.oid) where p.relname = '" + parent_name + "'")
    prog = len(children)
    count = 0
    for child in children:
        if count % 10 == 0:
            plpy.notice('%s : %s / %s' % (child['child'], str(count), str(prog)))
        plpy.execute("Create index on %s using %s (%s)" % (child['child'], index_type, col_name))
        count += 1
    plpy.notice('DONE')
$_function$;
```